# How to really easily save all tagged attachments in mutt?

Tags: mutt

You can save all attachments via

1. tag all attachments via hitting <kbd>t</kbd>
2. <kbd>;</kbd>
3. <kbd>s</kbd>
4. choose destination directory and hit <kbd>a</kbd> (all)

This works but has following severe side effect: you have to hit n-times <kbd>enter</kbd> for n attachments.

That means even if there are no file name collisions in the destination directory.

This is also documented in the [Mutt FAQ](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Attachment).

Very inconvenient.

Some mutt users seem to recommend [piping messages to munpack](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.mail.mutt.user/1484/focus=1512) (example message linked). Good idea - but how to make Mutt prompt for a destination directory (as part of a `munpack` invoking macro)?

How do I construct such a macro? Or are there better solutions to this issue?

Comment: I believe the reason no one has answered your question with a mutt macro, is because `<tag-pattern>` does not work in attachment mode.  There is, therefore, no way to programmatically tag all attachments (a necessary condition to being able to do something useful with *all* of them).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could pipe the message to [ripmime](http://www.pldaniels.com/ripmime/), which lets you specify a destination directory on the command line...e.g.:

```
ripmime -i - -d ~/myfiles/
```

The `-i -` tells `ripmime` to read from standard input, and `-d` specifies a destination directory.  If that's too much typing, stick it in a shell script and call that (which will also make it easier if you want to use other of `ripmime`'s many options for controlling its behavior).

If you add a macro like this to your configuration:

```
macro index,pager X "<pipe-message>ripmime -i - -d "
```

Then you can press "X", enter a destination directory, and press `<RETURN>` to run the command.

Comment: Fantastic!  Too bad I can upvote only once.  What's really great about this solution is it works for multiple messages as well.  Just tag 'em and `;|`.

Comment: Very nice, didn't work for multiple tagged message though, @AryehLeibTaurog you just press `t` and then `X`?

Comment: @Alex `t` to tag, `;`, to operate on all tagged messages, then `|` and the command to which you want to pipe.  (That isn’t an emoticon, it’s the command.)  If you want to use the macro above, the combination is `t;X`.

Comment: Careful @AryehLeibTaurog, on my system it seems to work but it doesn't, it extracts some file but not all, and it gives no errors, if I use a shell for loop and pipe the mail files to ripmime it works, maybe because I'm using Maildir and not mbox